# Standardized list of Topics per Record

Tags: topics

Good afternoon everyone,

Having learned that tags cannot be reported on, our organization is thinking of using Topics instead to categorize records. Is there a way to have a standardized set of "Topics" to pick from when attributing topics to an object? It seems that any user with Read/Edit permissions can type any phrase and it appends it as a topic.

We want to limit that to specific static categories. Tags allowed that, but you cannot create a view or report based on tags.